# How to set up Organizational Authentication in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, owin, visual-studio-2015, azure-active-directory, katana

I am creating a new ASP.NET 5.0 website based on Owin and Katana in Visual Studio 2015 RC. I would like the authentication to this website to use Windows Azure Active Directory.

In Visual Studio 2013, I was able to choose Organizational Accounts for this purpose. The wizard allowed me to add the URL to my Azure Active Directory and I was all set. In Visual Studio 2015 however, all I see is No Authentication and Individual Authentication. So how do I configure Organizational Authentication?

EDIT 1:

If I use one of these templates, I see a Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
```

This method only has access to Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.IApplicationBuilder instance and not to Owin.IAppBuilder instance, which is needed for the following method call

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication()
```

The following link shows that this is on purpose.

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/14/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap.aspx
```

The article further pointed to the following link which has code (written by Thinktecture guys) that takes in an IApplicationBuilder and returns an IAppBuilder as required:

```
https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge/KAppBuilderExtensions.cs
```

The only thing I wasn't able to figure from this sample is how to register the IDataProtectionProvider needed in the following line of code:

```
var provider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to chose 'No authentication' and add the necessary NuGet packages manually:

```
 - Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions
 - System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
 - Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
 - Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
 - Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

Then add a Startup.Auth.cs file with this method:

```
public partial class Startup
{
//...
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri);
        });
}
```

See the [Azure AD samples](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet) on Github for more detailed instructions.

Comment: How is the ConfigureAuth method called? I can add a call to it from the 'No Authentication' template generated Configure method, but the Configure method only has access to Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.IApplicationBuilder instance and not Owin.IAppBuilder instance.

Comment: You add an OWIN startup class (Add new item) and from it's Configuration method call the ConfigureAuth method. See also the linked example.